# parse file displays random alphanumeric text in textView Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, parse-platform, textview

I am getting a parse file back from parse.com which is a string message and displaying it in textView.

```
ParseFile file = message.getParseFile(ParseConstants.KEY_FILE);
        String filePath = file.getDataInBackground().toString(); 

        if (messageType.equals("string")){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), StringActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("file", filePath);
```

string activity class i try to display file in textView:

```
 protected TextView mDisplay;
 mDisplay = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stringDisplay);

 String mess = getIntent().getStringExtra("file");

 byte[] by = mess.getBytes();
 String filePath =new String(by);
 mDisplay.setText(filePath);
```

whats displayed in the textView is this `bolts.Task@12af9f90` random numbers.

how can i get the string to display?

Comment: `file.getDataInBackground()` will retrun a [Task](http://boltsframework.github.io/docs/android/bolts/Task.html?is-external=true) Object

Comment: so how should i do it to get a string?

Comment: Yo want the url of the file? Why not use `file.getUrl()`?

Comment: because it displays the url in the textview and not the string

Comment: is there a way to use `file.geturl()` and display the string

Comment: So, you want the content of the file, not the url?

Comment: yes i want the string stored in the file and not the url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get you the content of the file:

```
String fileContent = "";
try {
    fileContent = new String(file.getData());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: it has a red line under `(file.getdata())' and says unhandled:exception com.parse.parseException

Comment: Put it inside a try catch block. EDITED

Comment: one moment also should i leave this part as it is ` byte[] by = mess.getBytes();
 String filePath =new String(by);`

Comment: so just put mess from string mess into mdisplay.settext

Comment: Thank you very much my friend it worked! i have been stuck on this problem for a while. thank you

Comment: @smithyy Glad I can help.